# XPath select child if child exists, else select parent

Tags: xpath

I am dealing with elements that sometimes contain their own text, and sometimes contain a span with the text.  I'm generating an xpath in my program to get the elements I need based on the title attribute, so I'm using a template like this:

```bash
//div[@class='grid-canvas']//*[@title='Row %d column %s']
```

This works perfectly for elements that have their own text.  But if they keep their text inside a child span, then I have to change my xpath template:

```bash
//div[@class='grid-canvas']//*[@title='Row %d column %s']/span
```

I really just want to use one template for my xpath.  Since I either want the parent if it has no children, or the child element (which is a span) if it exists, I figured something like `.[not(node())] | span` should work, so I tried this:

```bash
//div[@class='grid-canvas']//*[@title='Row %d column %s']/.[not(node())] | span
```

But it didn't work.  I can't figure out what I'm missing.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your third query start searching at the current context again – if you didn't set that somewhere else, it will be scan for a `<span/>` root element.

**XPath 1.0** does not allow alternations "in the middle" or at the end of a path, only as prefixes, so you will have to repeat the whole path:

```
//div[@class='grid-canvas']//*[@title='Row %d column %s']/span |
//div[@class='grid-canvas']//*[@title='Row %d column %s'][not(span)]
```

This will select all "sub"spans and those parent elements not containing a span element.

In **XPath 2.0**, you'd be able to do this if only one (or none) span elements exist:

```
//div[@class='grid-canvas']//*[@title='Row %d column %s']/(span, .)[1]
```

or for arbitrary numbers:

```
//div[@class='grid-canvas']//*[@title='Row %d column %s']/(span, .[not(span)])
```