# Select child of element if exists, else take parent

Tags: xpath, ranorex

I want to catch the error message text from within a `<span>` tag, or if it does not exist, from its parent, a `div` tag. For this I need a valid xpath expression that can handle both cases as one if possible.

Here is the html code.
It's either version 1:

```html
<div class='error-message'>
  some error message
</div>
```

or version 2:

```html
<div class='error-message'>
  <span>
    some other error message
  </span>
</div>
```

So the xpaths would be:

v1: `//div[@class='error-message']`

v2: `//div[@class='error-message']/span`

Now I need to combine (with some 'or' expression maybe?) v1 and v2 somehow.

If have tried:

- `//div[@class='error-message']/descendant-or-self::*` but it finds both elements when the span exists (would prefer the span!)
- `//div[@class='error-message']/descendant-or-self::span` but finds nothing when the span does not exist

I also tried, what was given in this answer: [XPath select child if child exists, else select parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736559/xpath-select-child-if-child-exists-else-select-parent) but using the code `.../(span, .[not(span)])` seems to be invalid, at least in Ranorex.

Answer (score 0):

You could try following approach:

```
//div[@class='error-message']/descendant-or-self::*[@innertext!='']
```

Note: there is a limitation that if the text content is empty, it will not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Since, you do not know if the error message is going to be present in the div tag or span tag, you can try the below approach

> .//unknown[@innertext~'error message']

Additionally, it will work if the object has been identified correctly up untill the div tag in the original post.